# Mocha -Parameter in mocked data

Tags: angularjs, mocking, mocha.js, sinon

I'm mocking a function called isLoggedIn():

```
auth = {
        isLoggedIn: function () {
            return true;
        }
};
```

and apply is in a beforeEach loop

```
beforeEach(function () {
    angular.mock.module(function ($provide) {
        $provide.value('Auth', auth);
    });

});
```

At the moment isLoggedIn() will always return true. This function needs to be able to return false for some particular tests.

Is there a way to pass a variable into the mock from my tests.

E.g. something like

```
var loggedIn = ;

auth = {
        isLoggedIn: function () {
            return loggedIn;
        }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can for instance put it inside your test:

```
var loggedIn;
beforeEach(function () {
    auth = {
        isLoggedIn: function () {
            return loggedIn;
        }
    };

    angular.mock.module(function ($provide) {
        $provide.value('Auth', auth);
    });

});
```

It is also possible to have it as a separate file, but for this example it seems overkill.